# Keras loaded model is Not working

Tags: tensorflow, model, keras, load

I trained a model with Keras, saved it using `model.save()`, and from [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model) i don't need to save any thing else or compile the model after loading.

When i load it to test it on different images it gives this error:

> totalMemory: 5.93GiB freeMemory: 5.41GiB 2018-05-17 10:10:53.265572: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1120] Creating
>   TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 0, name: GeForce GTX
>   1060 with Max-Q Design, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability:
>   6.1)
>
> 2018-05-17 10:10:55.939415: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create
>   cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
>
> 2018-05-17 10:10:55.939452:
>   E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] could not destroy
>   cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
>
> 2018-05-17 10:10:55.939459: F
>   tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:667] Check failed:
>   stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms(
>   conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo(), &algorithms)
>
> Aborted (core dumped)

Here is the code i am using:

```python
num_classes = 17
model = load_model('model.h5')


img1 = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("s_0.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), (24,24))
img2 = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("s_f.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), (24,24))
img3 = cv2.resize(cv2.cvtColor(cv2.imread("s_2.jpg"), cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB), (24,24))

X_test = np.array([img1,img2,img3])
Y_test = to_categorical(np.array([0,12,2]), num_classes)

Y_predict = model.predict(X_test)
print np.argmax(Y_predict,axis = 1)
```

When i use the exact code for testing just after training (model is available not loaded), it works fine.

Comment: Looks like your CUDA  is broken. Have you tried a simple restart? If not, you can test if it's CUDA that is broken, by disabling the GPU. To do that run `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` assuming you are on a Linux distribution.

Comment: You are right, It worked when i disabled GPU @marcopah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your CUDA is broken. Test it by disabling the GPU `export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1`.